# macOS Activity Monitor - what is the starting time for CPU Time?

Tags: macos, display

I think I understand WHAT "CPU Time" is in the Activity Monitor (good discussion: [Mac OS X Activity Monitor - what does "CPU Time" tell me?](https://superuser.com/questions/218378/mac-os-x-activity-monitor-what-does-cpu-time-tell-me/218400#218400))

But, when is the starting time for the amount shown in "CPU Time"? I would have assumed boot time but that doesn't appear to me to be the case. And can it be reset if I want to, so that I can see what the CPU Time for a particular process will be in 5 minutes from a particular time?

Answer (score 0):

CPU Time starts when the process is launched and accumulates as the process
uses the CPU.

It cannot be reset, except by ending the process and restarting it.